# cron.php on IIS 7.5 windows 2008 server

Tags: php, windows, cron, sugarcrm, suitecrm

i'm running the suitecrm 7.1.1 on IIS 7.5 on windows 2008 server. trying to run the cron.php to make the AOD works;
The Cron batch file is killing me guys;
from the admin>scheduler i put all the 11 jobs to inactive and kept only 2 jobs to active ( Perform lucene Index and Optimize AOD Index ) just the jobs required for the AOD to work in global search.
i created a cron batch file with the following lines:

```
 cd c:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3
 php-cgi.exe -f c:\suitecrm\cron.php
```

I tested these two line with cmd prompt and the out put was cron.php is CLI Only
i find in some threads that the workaround for this issue is to comment out these lines from the cron.php file with // as follows:

```
//$sapi_type = php_sapi_name();
//if (substr($sapi_type, 0, 3) !='cli') {
// sugar_die("cron.php is CLI only.");
```

When running with the cmd prompt don't show any message, nothing in the log file but the windows task scheduler results is (0xFF) after each time is executed.
Now. i don't know if the cron is running or not and if this setup is correct and nothing is missing?
can anyone tried this cron on windows help me please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `php.exe -f c:\suitecrm\cron.php` instead of `php-cgi.exe`

Full documentation for working with Schedulers is available at the SugarCRM Website at [Sugar Community Edition 6.5 Administration Guide](http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/01_Sugar_Editions/05_Sugar_Community_Edition/Sugar_Community_Edition_6.5/Administration_Guide/05_System/#Scheduler).

Comment: thank you for your help...already tried this but no success. still can't find out if it does run the cron or not

Comment: If you're not sure whether if not it's running, put your sugar log into debug level, run cron, and then check your sugarcrm.log file to see what happened.

Comment: Got lost in this hug file getting updated by 100 line every second...can you point me to something to determine if it is running properly or something missing? thank you!!

Comment: If it is being updated, something must be running. Is your system live/in-use? If not, that's cron running that is causing the logging.

Comment: what the cron debug log look like? 
05/14/14 18:34:52 [368][-none-][DEBUG] Found cache backend SugarCacheAPC
05/14/14 18:34:52 [368][-none-][DEBUG] Found cache backend SugarCacheFile
05/14/14 18:34:52 [368][-none-][DEBUG] Found cache backend SugarCacheMemcache
05/14/14 18:34:52 [368][-none-][DEBUG] Found cache backend SugarCacheMemcached
05/14/14 18:34:52 [368][-none-][DEBUG] Found cache backend SugarCacheMemory
05/14/14 18:34:52 [368][-none-][DEBUG] Using cache backend SugarCacheMemory, since 999 is less than 1000
05/14/14 18:34:52 [368][-none-][DEBUG] Found cache backend SugarCacheRedis ...

Comment: I guess it is working now since the Windows scheduler says results succesful (0x0) but the log is not updating anymore. i used php.exe instead of php-cgi.exe and remove the // from the cron.php add before (see the post).

Answer (score 0):

I haven’t been able to use the php.exe either in windows. As an alternative, I use the Task Scheduler.
When creating a new one, the Actions tab looks something like this,

```
Program/script:  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
Add arguments (optional):  http://localhost/backlog/loadclosedtickets.php
```

It will then load up that page at the time specified in the Triggers tag.  If you want the script to self-close after running, use,

```
echo "<script>window.open('', '_self', ''); window.close();</script>";
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but no succes, firefox/IE coulden't open the page, when tried doing it manullay (type the url: http://localhost/crm/cron.php it says no permission to access directories..from remote pc http://x.x.x.x/cron.php is redirected to http://x.x.x.x/index.php. after enabling directory browsing from the server it says not found...am I missing something ?

Comment: Without modifying core files, you will not be able to call cron.php from a web browser. It checks for that as a security precaution. The loadclosedtickets.php file mentioned here is not a SugarCRM file, must be something custom.